# How can set different font for different characters?

Tags: debian, fonts

OS and desktop info:

```
uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.140-1 (2022-09-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
sudo dpkg -s  lxde | grep Version
Version: 11
sudo dpkg -s lxappearance  | grep Version
Version: 0.6.3-1+b1
```

I have set `DejaVu Sans Mono Book` as default font in my os.
[image: default font in the os]

I wonder that which font the os will call to use when characters is chinese characters ?
Can i set some configuration file to make the os to call `DejaVu Sans Mono Book` for English characters and call  `Noto Sans CJK Sc Regular` for chinese characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is done by using `fontconfig`.

Basically, you create a `match` section, with a testing for language, and then provide a specific font name. Something like:

```
<match>
    <test name="lang" compare="eq">
        <string>en_US</string>
    </test>
    <edit name="family" mode="assign">
        <string>DejaVu Sans Mono Book</string>
    </edit>
</match>

<match>
    <test name="lang" compare="eq">
        <string>zh_CN</string>
    </test>
    <edit name="family" mode="assign">
        <string>Noto Sans CJK Sc</string>
    </edit>
</match>
```

Please take a look at official documentation, it even has an example for your case
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html